# OAuth2 Popup Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm wondering how to open a new popup window in the browser and have the user complete an OAuth2 prompt there. After the OAuth2 prompt is completed, I want it to close that window and then the main window redirects to a dashboard.
Thanks.

Comment: your question is a bit vague, but the answer is probably to use an iFrame

Comment: Its a vague question and the answer could be large. I'll give you a hint: window.open()